# Select object in an html table cell changes to default value when swapping rows

Tags: javascript, html

First of all I would like help/answers in **JavaScript** and not in **jQuery**.

I have a simple html table that has five attributes, and in one of these attributes there is an Select object. I can add these objects dynamically when inserting new tuples but problems occur when i try to swap two rows with each other.

My row swap function works by taking the current row and swap the content with either the row under or over the current one, depending on which button the user clicks on.

The swap rows function:

```
    function moveRow(rowId, move) {
  var rows = document.getElementById('myTable').rows; // Get the rows from table
  var oldRow = rows[rowId].innerHTML; // rowId is the current row that is selected 
  var newRow = rows[rowId+move].innerHTML; // The new row, either above or under the currently selected one.

  if (rowId == 1 && move != 1){ // if the current row is 1, then you cannot swap it with row "0" because it is the table head with the attributes name.
    return;
  }else{
      rows[rowId].innerHTML = newRow; // Swap the new with the old 
      rows[rowId+move].innerHTML = oldRow; // Swap old with the new.

  }
```

But the drop down menu resets to it's original value (which is the first entry in the list) when i swap the rows. So my question is how can you "save" the value from a previous row into the "new" row so to speak. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the fiddle, the important parts of the code is there.
http://jsfiddle.net/ur9mG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're "moving" the row by grabbing the `innerHTML` property of the row, which doesn't include any state that the user has changed. Instead, move the entire DOM row.

Unfortunately, you can't use the `rows` array for that, as it is read only. So you'll have to manipulate the DOM. Note that this relies on the fact that you're being a good developer and using `tbody` tags to separate your table header from table body. :)

**[(DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/S2A7T/)**

```
function moveRow(index, direction) {
    var rows, rowToMove, pivotRow, tbody;
    tbody = document.getElementById('myTable').tBodies[0];
    rows = tbody.rows;

    // Sanity checking
    if (index === 0 && direction === -1) {
        return;
    }
    if (index === rows.length - 1 && direction === 1) {
        return;
    }

    rowToMove = rows[index];
    pivotRow = rows[index + direction];
    tbody.removeChild(rowToMove);
    if (direction === 1) {
        tbody.insertBefore(rowToMove, pivotRow.nextSibling);
    } else {
        tbody.insertBefore(rowToMove, pivotRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Only problem is that in my code that selects the row (it is a basic highlight) the first row in the table actually starts with the index 1 and not 0. How would i modify your example for this? Thanks!

Comment: Decrement the incoming index as the first line of the function: `index--; // selection code is 1-based`

Comment: Now it works exactly like i wanted it to! Thank you very much!